# Setting proxy settings for Flash Player

Tags: flash

I asked Google. But there is no working answer for it. 
I checked "right click -> global setings" and found no proxy setting in macromedia.com. 
Can anyone know how to configure proxy settings for flash player?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: flash player is known as the best secure platform for rtmp and other way so i dont think they will show you how to break their security with man in the middle attack ! me too im searching ...

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player connects directly to its destination, not through the web browser. Since there is no known way to set up proxy settings for Flash, you have to use a workaround like described in the link below.

[http://www.digitalacetone.com/2010/08/flash-player-can-reveal-your-true-ip-address-when-using-ssh-tunel-for-web-browser-proxy/](http://web.archive.org/web/20101125075327/http://www.digitalacetone.com/2010/08/flash-player-can-reveal-your-true-ip-address-when-using-ssh-tunel-for-web-browser-proxy/)

Comment: Just web-archived it: http://web.archive.org/web/20101125075327/http://www.digitalacetone.com/2010/08/flash-player-can-reveal-your-true-ip-address-when-using-ssh-tunel-for-web-browser-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player uses system proxy settings.So you have to change system proxy settings by  navigating to :
`Control Panel=> Network and Internet Connections => Internet Options => Connections =>` Select your profile and change proxy settings then click ok.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, flash player gets proxy settings [from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163174/flash-applications-proxy-use), where it is embedded in.
So, you can set proxy server etc. in your browser.

In case you use flash embedded in your own application, it gets proxy settings from IE.
To override their, you can intercept WinInet functions **InternetConnect** (and call **InternetSetOption** to set proxy address and port) and **InternetOpen** (to set proxy login and password).