# Flash applications proxy use

Tags: flash, proxy

Are flash applications forced to use a browser's set proxy.

Such as a proxy that has been set on foxy proxy.
Or will it be treated as a separate application that can see the user's real IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for most HTTP stuff, yes, Flash will use the browser defined proxy. There are exceptions to this such as FileReference uploads and if you roll your own HTTP stack using the socket stuff available in Flash, but then you're into Socket Policy Server issues.

In short, yes, Flash uses the browser proxy (or rather leverages the browser's http stack)