# Set proxy server for a thread

Tags: c#, .net, flash, proxy

I have a Flash swf written to run inside a webbrowser object.  When executed the swf connects to our web server to get data.
If the webbrowser is bound to a proxy server the swf fails due to IP addresses not matching.  The initial page request shows the requesting IP correctly as the proxy server but when the Flash swf directly connects and requests data, it is not being forced through the proxy and shows as a IP address different than the requesting page and fails security checks.
How can I force the Flash requests through the same proxy that the webbrowser object is bound to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640384/setting-proxy-settings-for-flash-player

Comment: That describes the FlashPlayer executable, not the SWF that runs in a web browser.  It uses the proxy server settings for the entire computer, not isolated to a thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163174/flash-applications-proxy-use
Says that it takes the proxy settings from the webbrowser but in my case it is not.

Comment: _"When executed the swf connects to **our web server** to get data"_ so how does it know your web server address? Is your address mentioned anywhere during the configuration of object/embed settings (in html code or some XML file)? Also it sounds like your SWF reads the address bar of browser address to generate what (it thinks) is the final server path. In that case simply don't use a proxy or else change the AS3 code to account for proxy & compile a new SWF. As a final test, using desktop browser with proxy add-on, can your SWF connect okay?

Comment: _"If the webbrowser is bound to a proxy server the swf fails due to IP addresses not matching."_ ... About desktop browser test.. Try **[ZenMate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-vpn-best-cyber-se/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme?hl=en)** for Chrome. Change your IP address (choose a country). Now in Chrome go to your SWF (embedded on html page saved on web server). If it connects okay then problem is not proxy servers. Perhaps involving a `.net` code & also a proxy server on top means to re-edit the AS3 code & compile a new SWF, adjusting code to account for extra conditions.

Comment: The swf connects to our web servers both by URL and direct IP.  It does not read the address bar.  I can use a 3rd party program such as Proxifier and force all communications from the application through a given proxy server and it works fine for a single node.  But I cannot run multiple nodes at once then because some point at different proxyservers and get forced through a single one determined by the 3rd party application.

Comment: Since it is a multi-node application, I am trying to figure out how to override it programmically.